# Using destructuring within import statement

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have two files- `/utils/BroadcasterEmbed.js` and `/commands/broadcaster.js`. Importing `BroadcasterEmbed.js` to `broadcaster.js` is the goal. When I test the below code, however, I get the following error `TypeError: BroadcasterEmbed is not a constructor`

I know this is possible considering an open source implementation I came across. Am I missing something?

BroadcasterEmbed.js

```
const { RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class BroadcasterEmbed extends RichEmbed {
    constructor(data = {}) {
        super(data);
    }
}
```

broadcaster.js

```
const { BroadcasterEmbed } = require('../')

exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    ...

    message.channel.send(new BroadcasterEmbed().setDescription('hello'));

    ...
}
```

Comment: The class is at the root level. You dont need to destructure. You are trying to destructure the class out of itself.

Comment: You also need to put the explicit file name in the require statement since the file name that holds that class isn't index.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
module.exports = class BroadcasterEmbed extends RichEmbed {
```

This means that the *whole module*, when `require`d, evaluates to what is on the other side of the `=` - that is, the class. Don't try to destructure, instead, just require the plain class:

```
const BroadcasterEmbed = require('../')
```

You would use destructuring if you assigned the class to a *property* of the original `module.exports` object, eg:

```
module.exports.BroadcasterEmbed = class...
```

and then

```
const { BroadcasterEmbed } = require('../')
```

Comment: Thank you, that appears to work! If you don't mind- is there a reason why it works in the following instance?

https://github.com/SwitchbladeBot/switchblade/blob/d3f1a16e450b9cc3be0d7b209fcf1d6f4647f37a/src/structures/SwitchbladeEmbed.js

https://github.com/SwitchbladeBot/switchblade/blob/d3f1a16e450b9cc3be0d7b209fcf1d6f4647f37a/src/listeners/GuildLogging.js

Comment: I'm not sure about Discord, I've never used it, I don't know where `RichEmbed` is defined in their source. But for the other link, the [index.js](https://github.com/SwitchbladeBot/switchblade/blob/d3f1a16e450b9cc3be0d7b209fcf1d6f4647f37a/src/index.js) file exports an object which has those 3 properties, `{ EventListener, SwitchbladeEmbed, Constants }`, among others, so the destructuring works.

Comment: I completely missed the `index.js`. That explains a lot. Your explanation has been most helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Broadcaster.js should have this import statenent:

```
const BroadcasterEmbed = require('../BroadcasterEmbed.js')
```

The class is at the root level. You dont need to destructure. You are trying to destructure the class out of itself.

You also need to put the explicit file name in the require statement since the file name that holds that class isn't `index.js`.